# dllimport: Passed argument is corrupt when using mangled names

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

In my attempt to use a DLL having mangled names I see an odd, but consistent, behaviour where the last argument passed is corrupted/uninitialized.

When I compile the code below using 'extern "C"' it works fine, but I would very much like the possibility of overloaded methods hence the use of mangled names. Everything is compiled in 64-bit.

MyDll.h:

```
#define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
class myDll
{
    public:
    MYDLL_API int Add(int, int);
    MYDLL_API int Sub(int, int);
};
```

myDll.cpp:

```
int myDll::Add(int a, int b)
{
    printf("a is %d, b is %d\n", a, b);
    return a + b;
}

int myDll::Sub(int a, int b)
{
    printf("a is %d, b is %d\n", a, b);
    return a - b;

}
```

Output from dumpbin:

```
Dump of file .\myDll.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for myDll.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    FFFFFFFF time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0001101E ?Add@myDll@@QEAAHHH@Z = @ILT+25(?Add@myDll@@QEAAHHH@Z)
          2    1 0001131B ?Sub@myDll@@QEAAHHH@Z = @ILT+790(?Sub@myDll@@QEAAHHH@Z)
```

The application where I import the DLL is written in C#

```
namespace UseMyDll
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = Add(1, 2);
            int b = Sub(2, 1);
        }

        [DllImport("myDll.dll",
            EntryPoint = "?Add@myDll@@QEAAHHH@Z",
            ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Add(int a, int b);

        [DllImport("myDll.dll",
            EntryPoint = "?Sub@myDll@@QEAAHHH@Z",
            ExactSpelling = true,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Sub(int a, int b);
    }
}
```

Output from running the C# program:

```
a is 2, b is -1588955232
a is 1, b is -1588955232
```

As can be seen from the program output the last parameter passed is not quite what I expect. Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Forgive any ignorance, but I see no instance of `myDll` created. Since `myDll` is a class, and those functions are non-static member functions, where is the instance of `myDll` created?

Comment: This code is plain wrong. You can't export instance methods like that. Use static methods or good old fashioned free standing functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and David What a rookie mistake! Thanks for your pointer! It works now.